# How to get the latest Transfer event transactions of a token on RSK from Covalent DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rsk

I am querying the Covalent database in order to get information about rUSDT token Transfer transactions on RSK. The token address on the RSK blockchain is as below:

`0xEf213441a85DF4d7acBdAe0Cf78004E1e486BB96`

The transfer event log's hash is as below:

`0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`

Here is my query as below:

```
SELECT
    t.signed_at, t.fees_paid
FROM chain_rsk_mainnet.block_log_events e
INNER JOIN chain_rsk_mainnet.block_transactions t ON
  e.block_id = t.block_id
  AND e.tx_offset = t.tx_offset
WHERE
  e.topics @> array[E'\\xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'::bytea]
  AND e.topics[1] = E'\\xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'
  AND e.sender = E'\\xEf213441a85DF4d7acBdAe0Cf78004E1e486BB96'
ORDER BY t.signed_at DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

I am expecting to get the transaction gas fees for the latest 1000 transfer events, but for some reason I never get a response for this query. Can someone tell me what can be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not order by time field because `t.signed_at` is not an indexed field whereas `e.block_id` and `e.tx_offset` are. Order by both of them.

Replace this statement

```
ORDER BY t.signed_at DESC
```

with this one

```
ORDER BY e.block_id DESC, e.tx_offset DESC
```

so that the the final query is as follows

```
SELECT
    t.signed_at, t.fees_paid 
FROM chain_rsk_mainnet.block_log_events e 
INNER JOIN chain_rsk_mainnet.block_transactions t ON
  e.block_id = t.block_id
  AND e.tx_offset = t.tx_offset
WHERE 
  e.topics @> array[E'\\xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'::bytea]
  AND e.topics[1] = E'\\xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'
  AND e.sender = E'\\xEf213441a85DF4d7acBdAe0Cf78004E1e486BB96'
ORDER BY e.block_id DESC, e.tx_offset DESC
LIMIT 1000
```